# How to compute the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (t)}{t}e^{ipt} dt$ using Jordan's lemma

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration

My approach so far has been to separate $\sin(t)$ as a sum of exponentials to re-write the integral as a sum of two integrals where Jordan's Lemma can be easily applied for $p>0$:

$$\begin{align}\sin(t)&=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{it} - e^{-it})\\
\therefore \frac{sin(t)}{(t)}e^{ipt} &= \frac{e^{ipt}}{2ti}(e^{it} - e^{-it})\\
&= \frac{ie^{-it}}{2t}e^{ipt} - \frac{ie^{it}}{2t}e^{ipt}\end{align}$$

Hence, the original integral is re-writed as:

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (t)}{t}e^{ipt} dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ie^{-it}}{2t}e^{ipt} dt - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ie^{it}}{2t}e^{ipt}dt$$

The issue I'm facing is trying to transform $f(t)$ into a complex valued function $f(z)$ to find the relevant singularities in order to compute their respective residues. My attempt (for the second integral) goes as follows:

$$z = e^{it}\therefore dz = ie^{it}dt\therefore dt = \frac{dz}{iz}$$

Additionally:

$$z = e^{it}\therefore it = \ln(z)\therefore t = -i\ln(z)$$

Substituting this results in $f(t)$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ie^{it}}{2t}e^{ipt}dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{-2i\ln(z)}e^{ipt}dz$$

But if this transformation is correct, I would face the issue of attempting to find the singularities of a multivalued function (the logarithm of a complex number) and I do not know as of now how to find them.

Answer (score 1):

> $$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (t)}{t}e^{ipt} dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ie^{-it}}{2t}e^{ipt} dt - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ie^{it}}{2t}e^{ipt}dt$$

From this step, you can use Jordan's lemma immediately. For the second term, since $p>0$, you can choose the semi-circle on the upper half plane to apply Jordan's lemma. For the first term, you need to be careful,

(1) if $p=1$, the integrand is odd, hence the principle value is zero.

(2) if $p>1$, you choose the semi-circle on the upper half plane to apply Jordan's lemma.

(3) if $0<p<1$, you choose the semi-circle on the lower half plane to apply Jordan's lemma.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. But applying Jordan's lemma for both p>1 and p<1 would still require to identify the singularities of f(t) wouldn't it?

Comment: For $z=0$ you take a small semi-circle contour above it, which gives half of the residue at this simple pole. What you did is similar as the Dirichlet integral.